# Refreshing an image in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a div to hold a user's profile picture. To update it, the user chooses a new image which then replaces the old image in the div. Then the user hits updates to upload the new picture, but when I get the response from the server and the same page with the same div loads up, it populates the div with the old image. I traced this in the debugger. I stopped at the line before the div updates with the pictures and check it on the filesystem (the correct new picture is there), then I proceed in the debugger and it fills the div with the old picture. If I refresh the page after a second or two, the new image will appear.

The div picture container:

```
<div id="ProfilePictureBox"></div>
```

This function is called when the page loads to update the div

```
function preloadForm() {
    var url = '/FeatureServer/Authentication?action=getMyDetails&userName=' + userName;
    var req = $jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data, response, xhr) {
            var pic = data['ProfilePicture'];
            if (pic.length > 0) {
                pic = '/FeatureServer/' + pic;
                // pausing here and checking `pic` in the browser confirms its the correct image
                $jQuery("#ProfilePictureBox").css("background-image", 'url(' + pic + ')');
                // old image is loaded ^
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You might try adding a seed to the image URL to make sure you aren't getting a cached result.

Comment: @ajax81 What do you mean by adding a seed?

Comment: A timestamp added to the end of the URL will make it "different" from the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to add a timestamp kind of variable in the URL of image path so that the each time new result will display instead of cached or old result.

For example replace below :

```
pic = '/FeatureServer/' + pic;
```

With

```
pic = '/FeatureServer/' + pic + "?time=" + (new Date());
```

Above will add a new date/time each time when image get generated and path will be unique every time.

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: This isn't gonna work for me unfortunately. The server I'm working with is in charge of naming the files, and by not naming it with the same username.jpg, other parts of the system break b/c it won't be able to find the image it's looking for. It was programmed very poorly -__-

Comment: @Chris, in above code the name of image file wouldn't changed. Instead i am trying to show that you need to add a query string in your image path so that path will always be unique for img element each time.

Comment: It worked! I just wanna note I had to do `(new Date()).getTime()` for it to work. Date() returned the entire string of today. Thank you :)